# Drag & Drop tasks on webpage data from JSON-file. It drag all tasks, not just one

Tags: javascript, html, json, drag-and-drop, task

I got a webpage and are making a to-do list with drag & Drop function. The tasks are in a separately JSON-file. And depending on which day it is, it will only show the tasks for that day.
It works with displaying the right tasks, but when I'm dragging and drop one task, it take all tasks that are displaying, not just that one I want.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Arbetstavla</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="containerMaster">
        <div class="containerBoard">
            <div class="containerTeam" v-for="(container, containerIndex) in containers" :key="container.id" :id="container.id">
              <h2>Team {{ containerIndex + 1 }}</h2>
              <div class="flex-parent jc-center">
                <button class="newCardBtn" @click="addCard(containerIndex)">Lägg till kort</button>
                <button class="clearBtn" @click="removeContainer(containerIndex)">Ta bort Team</button>
              </div>
              <div class="cards" v-for="(card, cardIndex) in container.cards" :key="card.id" :id="card.id">
                <div class="container">
                   <h3>Ansvarsområden</h3>
                  <div class="drop-area" @dragover.prevent @drop="dropHandler">Släpp uppgifter här</div>
                </div>
                <button class="clearBtn" @click="removeCard(containerIndex, cardIndex)">Ta bort kort</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="containerRight">
            <div class="containerTask" >        
              <h1>UPPGIFTER</h1>
                  <ul class="cardTask" draggable="true" @dragstart="dragStartHandler">
                    <ul>
                      <li v-for="task in todayTasks" :key="task.id">
                        <input type="checkbox" v-model="task.completed" @change="updateTask(task)">
                        <label class="checkedCross" for="task.completed"></label>
                        {{ task.task }}
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.22/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="js/move.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: [],
      weekday: ["SÖNDAG", "MÅNDAG", "TISDAG", "ONSDAG", "TORSDAG", "FREDAG", "LÖRDAG"],
      todayTasks: [],
      day: "",
      containers: [
        {
          id: 'container-1',
          cards: [
            {
              id: 'card-1',
              tasks: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      dragData: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadTasks();
  },
  methods: {
    addContainer() {
      const id = `container-${this.containers.length + 1}`;
      this.containers.push({ id, cards: [] });
    },
    addCard(containerIndex) {
      const id = `card-${this.containers[containerIndex].cards.length + 1}`;
      this.containers[containerIndex].cards.push({ id, tasks: [] });
    },
    removeCard(containerIndex, cardIndex) {
      this.containers[containerIndex].cards.splice(cardIndex, 1);
    },
    removeContainer(containerIndex) {
      this.containers.splice(containerIndex, 1);
    },
    addTask(cardIndex) {
      const id = `cardTask-${this.containers[0].cards[cardIndex].tasks.length + 1}`;
      this.containers[0].cards[cardIndex].tasks.push({ id, text: `Task ${id}` });
    },
    dragStartHandler(event) {
      this.dragData = event.target;
    },
    dropHandler(event) {
      const droparea = event.target.closest('.drop-area');
      if (this.dragData.classList.contains('cardTask') && droparea) {
        droparea.appendChild(this.dragData);
      }
    },
    loadTasks() {
        fetch("tasks.json")
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            this.tasks = data;
            this.getTodayTasks();
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error loading tasks:", error);
          });
      },
      getTodayTasks() {
        const d = new Date();
        const day = this.weekday[d.getDay()];

        this.todayTasks = this.tasks.filter(task => task.day === day);
      },
      updateTask(task) {
      console.log("completed:", task.completed);
    }
    },
    computed: {
      todayDay() {
        const d = new Date();
        const day = this.weekday[d.getDay()];
        return day;
      }
    }
  });

  app.mount('#app');
```

JSON

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "day": "MÅNDAG",
      "task": "Task 1 for Monday"
    },    
    {
      "id": 2,
      "day": "ONSDAG",
      "task": "Task 2 for Monday"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "day": "ONSDAG",
      "task": "Task 1 for Tuesday"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).